# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Can anybody suggest for what values of $p$,

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^{p}}dx$

converge ?

I have tried so far $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx$

For $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx$ I apply limit comparison test $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}}{\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x} =-1$ hence it $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx$ converge iff $p<2$

For $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx$ i have applied again limit comparison test I found it converge iff $p>1$ by taking denominator function $\frac{1}{x^{p}}$

so the $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x^p}dx$ converge iff $p\in [1,2]$

is it alright?

Comment: $\large p \in \left(1,2\right)$.

Comment: @Felix: you are right

Answer (score 2):

You can start by writing $$-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}x^{1-p} dx=-\int_{0}^{\infty} F(x)x^{1-p} dx$$

We already know how to deal with $x^{1-p}$. Now, as $x\to 0$, $F(x)\to 1$ and as $x\to \infty$, $F(x)\sim x^{-1}$, and $F$ is continuous, positive (in fact its "positive" range is $(0,1]$) and decreasing over $x>0$. You know that $$\int_0^1 x^{-\alpha} dx$$ converges for $\alpha<1$ and that $$\int_1^\infty x^{-\beta} dx$$ converges for $\beta >1$. Now, you integral is similar $ x^{1-p}$ near the origin and similar to $x^{-p}$ for large values of $x$. Can you make a guess as to where $p$ should fall and then prove it?

Comment: fine. thank you very much @Pedro Tamaroff

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

\begin{align}
{\expo{-x} - 1 \over x^{p}} &\sim\ -\,{1 \over x^{p - 1}}\quad\mbox{when}\quad
x \sim 0\quad\imp\quad 2 - p > 0 \ \imp \ p < 2
\\[3mm]
{\expo{-x} - 1 \over x^{p}} &\sim\ -\,{1 \over x^{p}}\quad\mbox{when}\quad
x \gg 1\quad\imp\quad p - 1 > 0\ \imp\ p > 1
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} -1 \over x^{p}}\,\dd x\quad \color{#000000}{\tt converges}\ \mbox{whenever}\quad
1 < p < 2}
$$

Comment: fine. thank you very much @Felix Marin

Comment: @RealHilbert You're welcme. Thanks.

Comment: It is usually polite not to give a full answer if someone has given a partial answer before you in hopes the OP will sort the question on his/her own.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I got your point. I'll be careful in the future. The OP should always make some effort. Thanks.